# How to detect implicit commit in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, commit, implicit

I would like to know is it possible to detect broken transactions caused by implicit commit or no.
Currently I don't know how to check if transactions in my application works without implicit commit. Also I can't see if my changes don't lead to implicit commit.

It looks like the easiest way to control it is to force MySQL to throw error instead of implicit commit but I don't know how to configure it.

Sometime it's hard to see the problem in the code so MySQL error could be efficient way to protect transaction.

Example below will show how much implicit commit can be hidden..

Code with implicit commit:

```
public function loadDataToDb(XMLReader $productXML)
{
    $this->stats = $this->getProductImporter()->initStats();

    while ($productXML->read()) {

        if ($productXML->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $productXML->name == 'product') {
            $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
            $product = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($productXML->expand(), true));
            $this->getDBConnection()->beginTransaction();
            try {
                $this->getStorage()->addProduct($product);
                $this->getDBConnection()->commit();
                $this->stats['valid_skus'][trim($product->sku)] = true;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->getDBConnection()->rollBack();
                $this->stats['invalid_skus'][trim($product->sku)] = true;
                $this->productLog('Product {' . $product->sku . '} skipped:' . $e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Fixed code:

```
public function loadDataToDb(XMLReader $productXML)
{
    $this->stats = $this->getProductImporter()->initStats();
    $storage = $this->getStorage();

    while ($productXML->read()) {

        if ($productXML->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $productXML->name == 'product') {
            $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
            $product = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($productXML->expand(), true));
            $this->getDBConnection()->beginTransaction();
            try {
                $storage->addProduct($product);
                $this->getDBConnection()->commit();
                $this->stats['valid_skus'][trim($product->sku)] = true;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->getDBConnection()->rollBack();
                $this->stats['invalid_skus'][trim($product->sku)] = true;
                $this->productLog('Product {' . $product->sku . '} skipped:' . $e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation: At first call of function $this->getStorage() it creates Storage object that performs truncates in it's __constructor. So transaction is broken and it's not possible to detect it without debugging.

In such cases pdo exception will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you use another catch block before the normal exception and catch a PDO Exception?

```
public function loadDataToDb(XMLReader $productXML)
```

{
    $this->stats = $this->getProductImporter()->initStats();
    $storage = $this->getStorage();

```
while ($productXML->read()) {

    if ($productXML->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $productXML->name == 'product') {
        $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
        $product = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($productXML->expand(), true));
        $this->getDBConnection()->beginTransaction();
        try {
            $storage->addProduct($product);
            $this->getDBConnection()->commit();
            $this->stats['valid_skus'][trim($product->sku)] = true;
        } catch (PDOException $pdo) {
            $this->getDBConnection()->rollBack();
            $this->stats['invalid_skus'][trim($product->sku)] = true;
            $this->productLog('Product database error:  {' . $product->sku . '} skipped:' . $e);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->productLog('Product error:'. $e);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: there is not pdo exception